# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This error happened when I tried to get access to the page. I didn't get errors when I created the tables, but seems like there are problems still.

The models are like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    sell_items = db.relationship('Item', backref='user')

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    item_image = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float(10), index=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='sell_items')
```

The whole error message is this

```
Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|User|user'. Original exception was: Error creating backref 'user' on relationship 'User.sell_items': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Item|item'
```

How can I fix this? What I want to do is to refer to `username` who sells the item, but I cannot. There is a problem with the relationships between the models.

Comment: Related, and explains the difference between `backref` and `back_populates` very well: [When do I need to use sqlalchemy back_populates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869793/when-do-i-need-to-use-sqlalchemy-back-populates) Here's another related Q/A: [SQLAlchemy relationship raise Argument error when creating backref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473206/sqlalchemy-relationship-raise-argument-error-when-creating-backref), and [sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399602/sqlalchemy-exc-argumenterror-error-creating-backref).

Comment: [SQLAlchemy relationship error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394666/sqlalchemy-relationship-error)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use `backref` the backwards relationship is automatically created, so it should only be used in one side of the relationship. In your case, you can remove the `sell_items` in the `User` model and the `User` model will automatically get a relationship from `Item`.

To declare the relationshiop on both sides (in case you want to customize its name, for example, use `back_populates='name_of_relationship_on_other_model'`.

Comment: Actually I still couldn't solve the problem that I cannot refer to like itam.user.username.
I'm really confused.

Comment: That sounds like another error for another question – though do your research first. Please refrain from moving the goal post.

Answer (score 0):

in your Item class, replace this line

`user = db.relationship('User', backref='sell_items')`

with this line

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

it should work that way, from there you can query like this `item = Item.query.first()`, then `item.sell_items`... to get the user who posted the item.

i hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing this when you refactor  your project it could simply be the way the pycharm vm is loading the classes.

In my case a adding the dependants  MedicalRecord
TakenMedication
UserDrugDosage
QuestionAndAnswer first before the model declaration solved the issue

```
from db.models.dbqanda import QuestionAndAnswer
from db.models.medical_jobs import MedicalRecord
from db.models.medication import TakenMedication, UserDrugDosage
 MedicalRecord
 TakenMedication
 UserDrugDosage
 QuestionAndAnswer

class User(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(500), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(200), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)  # doctors will be super users
    jobs = relationship("MedicalRecord", back_populates="owner")
    profile = relationship("UserProfile", back_populates="owner")
    drug_dosage = relationship("UserDrugDosage", back_populates="owner")
    medication = relationship("TakenMedication", back_populates="owner")
    questions = relationship("QuestionAndAnswer", back_populates="owner")
    notes = relationship("Notes", back_populates="owner")
```